# Use webpack to generate HTML asset that uses the JS bundle

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

**The problem**: I use Webpack and I need to display part of my page in an IFRAME. The markup for the IFRAME's content is static and it includes a few JS libraries and some custom JS logic.

**The idea**: I wanted to bundle up all JS dependencies of the page rendered in the IFRAME alongside my other Webpack bundles and build the page itself as a static HTML asset that I can then reference from the host page as the IFRAME's `src`.

**Method 1**: I tried to use Webpack's `file!val!html?attrs=script:src` transform for my static HTML file.

**Files**

```
page/
  lib/
    - jquery.js
    - ...
  - page.html
  - page.js
```

**page.html**

```
...
<script src="./page.js"></script>
...
```

**page.js**

```
const $ = require('./lib/jquery.js');
window.foo = () => { ... };
```

**Webpack config**

```
{
  ...,
  entry: {
    main: [...],
    page: ['page/page.js']
  }
}
```

This almost worked, since the JS bundle and HTML asset were indeed generated and I could `require` the latter on the IFRAME host page, but the linked bundle `./page.js` failed to properly resolve as a URL (renders as `[Object]`). Tried `file!val!html?interpolate` with `<script src="${require('file!./page.js')}">`, which fails to locate the file altogether.

**Method 2**: Tried to use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` with the following config:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'page.html',
  template: 'page/page.html',
  chunks: ['page'],
  inject: 'head'
})
```

This too, almost worked, both the JS bundle and the `page.html` having been created. Contrary to the first method, JS bundle was properly linked here by the plugin. On the other hand, there seems to be no way to reference the generated HTML on my host page via `require` or any other  reliable means.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated